# scrolling tableview in scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

In my project, i have UIScrollView, now i have added an UITableView into scvRegister(scrollview) like the following:

```
autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 80, 220, 120) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[scvRegister addSubview:autocompleteTableView];
```

Everything is seem to be OK but, when i touch on TableView and scroll it -> ScrollView is moved and TableView has nothings change!

I have read some post about hittest event, but my interface is UIViewController, not UIScrollView so i could not override it.

```
@interface RegisterViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,BSKeyboardControlsDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Have any idea for this!
thks in advanced,

Comment: UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. In fact, it's enabled automatically I believe. self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

Comment: tks! but by default, is had been set to YES!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not really supposed to put a scrollView (UITableView is a scrollview subclass) inside of another scrollView. I'd suggest adding the table to self.view and positioning it appropriately on top of the scrollview.

Comment: I have many textField and i would add textField for autocomplete text. I could not put it on top. I have to fix: [scrollview setSrollEnable:NO]; -> my Table could be received touch event...

Comment: why should you put tableview in scrollview because table view is also one type of scrollview...

Answer (score 0):

Its late  but someone may need.
I sloved it by setting the inner tableview **scrollEnabled** to **YES** and **bounces** to **NO**

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    autocompleteTableView.bounces = NO;
    .......

}
```